# Parrot MiniDrone Rolling Spider programmable?

Tags: python, ar.drone

I want to know if Parrot MiniDrone Rolling Spider is programmable using python as primary development language? Is their any sdk that I could use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It is programmable. You have to use the ARDroneSDK3
https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3

It is not that well documented but if you have enough enthusiasm you could make it work and write your python scrips.

Comment: There's nothing at https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3 as of September 2016. The SDK now appears to live under https://github.com/Parrot-Developers

Comment: which of the packages?